# Windows 10 Domain Joined Shows Unidentified Netwokr

Tags: windows-10, dns

I have a number of Windows 10 computers on my Domain. After I joined the computer to the domain and restarted it would show the correct domain. When I restart again to do anything after that, the network will show up as Unidentified Network. I know the DNSs are correct. The IP Address is correct .There is no DHCP as this network is set statically per machine. I have tried changing the NLA service to Automatic (Start Delayed). I have tried reseting the network. I have tried removing it and rejoining it to the domain. I have tried disabling and reenabling the connection and all it gets is the Unidentified Network. Any suggestions on how to get it back the domain?

Comment: Is your Gateway address correct?

Comment: As @music2myear mentioned, your default gateway must be configured and reachable to identify the network. Further, to be identified as a domain network, at least one DC must be reachable on-link, which requires DNS to be working. I suspect your problem is related to the fact you're not using DHCP...

Comment: @music2myear I don't have a gateway addresss as we are not using a router. This is a statically set DNS environment.

Comment: Then that is the problem. Your gateway does not need to be connected to the internet. If your network is ad-hoc, then I don't believe it'll be able to be Identified and trusted. Though I am not a networking expert.